# MPI_Rank return same process number for all process

Tags: mpi, openmpi

I'm trying to run this sample hello world program with openmpi and mpirun on debian 7.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi/mpi.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
   int nProcId, nProcNo;

   int nNameLen;
   char szMachineName[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];

   MPI_Init (&argc, &argv); // Start up MPI

   MPI_Comm_size (MPI_COMM_WORLD,&nProcNo); // Find out number of processes
   MPI_Comm_rank (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nProcId); // Find out process rank
   MPI_Get_processor_name (szMachineName, &nNameLen); // Get machine name

   printf ("Hello World from process %d on %s\r\n", nProcId, szMachineName);

   if (nProcId == 0)
      printf ("Number of Processes: %d\r\n", nProcNo);

   MPI_Finalize (); // Shut down MPI

   return 0;
}
```

My problem is `MPI_Comm_Rank` returns 0 for all copies of the process. When I run this command on the shell:

```
mpirun -np 4  helloWorld
```

It produces this output:

```
Hello World from process 0 on debian
Number of Processes: 1
Hello World from process 0 on debian
Number of Processes: 1
Hello World from process 0 on debian
Number of Processes: 1
Hello World from process 0 on debian
Number of Processes: 1
```

Why is the number of processes still 1?

Comment: What command did you use to compile helloWorld?

Comment: I know this is a little late but mpicc helloWorld.c would normally create an executable called a.out. mpicc -o helloWorld helloWorld.c would create an executable called helloWorld.

Answer (score 18):

Make sure that both `mpicc` and `mpirun` come from **the same MPI implementation**. When `mpirun` fails to provide the necessary universe information to the launched processes, with the most common reason for that being that the executable was build against a different MPI implementation (or even a different version of the same implementation), `MPI_Init()` falls back to the so-called *singleton MPI initialisation* and creates an `MPI_COMM_WORLD` that only contains the calling process. Thus the result is many MPI processes within their own separate `MPI_COMM_WORLD` instances.

Usually commands like `mpicc --showme`, `which mpicc` and `which mpirun` could help you find out if that is the case indeed.

Comment: which mpicc and which mpirun both returns /usr/bin/mpicc and /usr/bin/mpirun

Comment: Which MPI implementation are you using?

Comment: I'm using libopenmpi-dev

Comment: I had the same problem. Removing openmpi and using only mpich solved my problem.

Comment: I have both openmpi and mpich installed on Mint 17 - and was switching between them using `update-alternatives --configure mpi`.  This however does _not_ switch out the mpiexec implementation, for which you must also do an `update-alternatives --configure mpirun`.