# MPI program executed in only one process against requested with many processes

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

I am a beginner trying to learn MPI. I have tried to run the following program downloaded from internet:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <mpi.h>

    int main (argc, argv)
         int argc;
         char *argv[];
    {
      int rank, size;

      MPI_Init (&argc, &argv);  /* starts MPI */
      MPI_Comm_rank (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);    /* get current process id */
      MPI_Comm_size (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);    /* get number of processes */
      printf( "Hello world from process %d of %d\n", rank, size );
      MPI_Finalize();
      return 0;
    }
```

The code has been compiled with `mpicc` and executed with `mpirun`.

```
mpicc HelloWorld.c
mpirun -np 4 a.out
```

The output is as follows:

```
Hello world from process 0 of 1
Hello world from process 0 of 1
Hello world from process 0 of 1
Hello world from process 0 of 1
```

My question is, why the output has generated only one process and not 4 processes as requested?

Comment: How many cores do you have? I managed to run it on my machine i7, 8 cores and got expected output.

Comment: Even I tried this on other pc and managed to get desired result. But in my pc, the issue persists. The `nproc` value from pc is 12.

Comment: I guess generating processes is core (hardware) independent.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MPI\_Rank return same process number for all process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20287564/mpi-rank-return-same-process-number-for-all-process)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried to follow the link of a discussion but `which mpicc` and `which mpirun` are returning the location on computer. Hence, I could not really make conclusion if they are from the same version or not. Is there any other way I could do it?

Comment: I have met the same problem. And finally I found that I installed openmpi and mpich simultaneously on my ubuntu. I uninstalled both of them completely and then only installed libmpich-dev. Then the problem was solved for me.

Answer (score -1):

This problem occurs when `mpicc` and `mpirun` are not from the same MPI Implementation.
You can do uninstall openmpi and mpich and install only mpich lib.
Run these commands in your terminal.
`sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove openmpi-bin`
`sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove mpich`
`sudo apt-get install mpich`

Answer (score -1):

The following solved my problem:

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove openmpi-bin
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove mpich
sudo apt-get install mpich
sudo apt install lam-runtime     
sudo apt install mpich           
sudo apt install openmpi-bin     
sudo apt install slurm-wlm-torque
```