# mpiexec and python mpi4py gives rank 0 and size 1

Tags: python, mpi, mpi4py, mpiexec

I have a problem with running a python Hello World mpi4py code on a virtual machine.

The hello.py code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#hello.py
from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD

size = comm.Get_size()
rank = comm.Get_rank()

print "hello world from process ", rank,"of", size
```

I've tried to run it using mpiexec and mpirun, but it is not running well.
The output:

```
$ mpirun -c 4 python hello.py 
hello world from process  0 of 1
hello world from process  0 of 1
hello world from process  0 of 1
hello world from process  0 of 1
```

And from mpiexec:

```
$ mpiexec -n 4 python hello.py 
hello world from process  0 of 1
hello world from process  0 of 1
hello world from process  0 of 1
hello world from process  0 of 1
```

They seem not getting rank and size of comm. What can cause this? How to solve it?

```
mpiexec --version
mpiexec (OpenRTE) 1.6.5

mpirun --version
mpirun (Open MPI) 1.6.5
```

The system is Ubuntu 14.04 on the Virtal Machine.

Any ideas why? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [MPI\_Rank return same process number for all process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20287564/mpi-rank-return-same-process-number-for-all-process)

Comment: Most likely, your mpi4py is built against a different MPI implementation than the mpiexec/mpirun you're using to run the program.  Does `mpi4py.get_config()` return compilers that are in the same path as your mpirun?

Comment: `mpi4py.get_config()` returns
 `{'mpicxx': '/usr/bin/mpicxx', 'mpif77': '/usr/bin/mpif77', 'mpicc': '/usr/bin/mpicc', 'mpif90': '/usr/bin/mpif90'}`

But I tried the same on my localhost and get the same output (the same config), and at my localhost the code works.

Comment: great ; now where is mpirun/mpi exec?  Eg, what's the output of which mpirun?

Comment: `$ which mpirun mpiexec
/usr/bin/mpirun
/usr/bin/mpiexec`

Comment: And whereis:

`mpirun: /usr/bin/mpirun.mpich
    /usr/bin/mpirun 
    /usr/bin/mpirun.openmpi
    /usr/bin/X11/mpirun.mpich 
    /usr/bin/X11/mpirun
    /usr/bin/X11/mpirun.openmpi
    /usr/share/man/man1/mpirun.1.gz`

    mpiexec: `/usr/bin/mpiexec.mpich 
    /usr/bin/mpiexec.hydra
    /usr/bin/mpiexec
    /usr/bin/mpiexec.openmpi
    /usr/bin/X11/mpiexec.mpich
    /usr/bin/X11/mpiexec.hydra
    /usr/bin/X11/mpiexec
    /usr/bin/X11/mpiexec.openmpi
    /usr/share/man/man1/mpiexec.1.gz`

Sorry for formatting, I'm just getting know how to use Stack Oerflow

Comment: Ok - it looks like there's both MPICH and OpenMPI versions (or at least stubs of versions) installed for MPI.  This is the canonical source of this problem - you have an mpi4py compiled with one implementation and are trying to run it with another.  Try either explicitly running with both mpirun.mpich and  mpirun.openmpi, or completely uninstall one or the other (including all libraries)

Comment: Yeah, the openmpi mpiexec version returned 0 and 1. The mpich mpiexec works great. 
I am really thankful for your help!

Answer (score 1):

As suggested above and in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20287564/mpi-rank-return-same-process-number-for-all-process) for C, this has to do with having `mpirun` coming from a different MPI than `mpi4py` was linked against.

In my case, and I suspect the same is true for many other Python users, this came from having originally installed `mpi4py` through `conda`, which pulled a non-system version of MPI into my `conda` -- i.e. `which mpirun` gave a path in my `conda` environment.

To solve the problem, I ran `conda remove mpi4py` and then `pip install mpi4py`, which seemed to rebuild `mpi4py` against the MPI in the `conda` environment and solved the issue.

Comment: Worked for me. Had to `module load OpenMPI` before pip installation.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when running the python module `emcee`. It would give me an error:

```
"ValueError: Tried to create an MPI pool, but there was only one MPI process available. 
Need at least two."
```

The solution I found for my particular cluster was to use a different MPI. My code worked with `intel-mpi` and `mpich2` but not `openmpi`. For this system, all I had to do was switch the MPI. In my `PBS` script I used `module load mpich2` instead of `module load openmpi`. In this case `mpiexec` and `mpirun` worked correctly.

Comment: Switch what? Switch where? I am trying to understand your post, I have the same problem as OP.

Comment: I edited the answer to clarify that I switched the MPI for my particular system.