# How to force mpi4py installation to use gnu MPI instead of intel MPI on cluster

Tags: python, mpi, mpi4py

## Problem

I'm trying to use `mpi4py` on a cluster. Because of other dependencies I have to use gnu, not intel. However, there are **both compiler versions on the cluster** and I don't manage to **force mpi4py to install with the gnu compilers**.

## Questions

- **How can I make mpi4py work with gnu instead of intel?**
- Why is mpi4py installed with intel even though I unloaded all intel modules?
- Why is mpi4py installed with intel despite me specifying `env MPICC`?

## Failed Attempts

I first tried to unload the intel modules and load a gnu openmpi module, such that I get:

```
me@cluster:~$ module purge
me@cluster:~$ module load python
me@cluster:~$ source .virtualenvs/py36env/bin/activate
(py36env) me@cluster:~$ module load openmpi/gcc/9.1/4.0.1 
(py36env) me@cluster:~$ module list
Currently Loaded Modulefiles:
  1) python/3.6              2) openmpi/gcc/9.1/4.0.1

(py36env) me@cluster:~$ which mpicc
/usr/local/Cluster-Apps/openmpi/gnu/4.0.1-gcc-9.1/bin/mpicc

(py36env) me@cluster:~$ mpicc --version
gcc (GCC) 9.1.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

(py36env) me@cluster:~$ which mpirun
/usr/local/Cluster-Apps/openmpi/gnu/4.0.1-gcc-9.1/bin/mpirun

(py36env) me@cluster:~$ mpirun --version
mpirun (Open MPI) 4.0.1

Report bugs to http://www.open-mpi.org/community/help/
```

However, when I pip install mpi4py it uses the intel compilers despite my efforts to unload them:

```
(py36env) me@cluster:~$ pip install mpi4py
Collecting mpi4py
Installing collected packages: mpi4py
Successfully installed mpi4py-3.0.2

(py36env) me@cluster:~$ python -c "import mpi4py; print(mpi4py.get_config())"
{'mpicc': '/usr/local/Cluster-Apps/intel/2017.4/compilers_and_libraries_2017.4.196/linux/mpi/intel64/bin/mpicc', 
 'mpicxx': '/usr/local/Cluster-Apps/intel/2017.4/compilers_and_libraries_2017.4.196/linux/mpi/intel64/bin/mpicxx', 
 'mpifort': '/usr/local/Cluster-Apps/intel/2017.4/compilers_and_libraries_2017.4.196/linux/mpi/intel64/bin/mpif90', 
 'mpif90': '/usr/local/Cluster-Apps/intel/2017.4/compilers_and_libraries_2017.4.196/linux/mpi/intel64/bin/mpif90', 
 'mpif77': '/usr/local/Cluster-Apps/intel/2017.4/compilers_and_libraries_2017.4.196/linux/mpi/intel64/bin/mpif77'}
```

I get the same result even when I try to specify the mpi environment with

```
$ env MPICC=/usr/local/Cluster-Apps/openmpi/gnu/4.0.1-gcc-9.1/bin/mpicc pip install mpi4py
```

as suggested in the Note at https://mpi4py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html#using-pip-or-easy-install.

## Errors

As pointed out in the comments to "[mpiexec and python mpi4py gives rank 0 and size 1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29264640/6135182)", having mpi4py being built against a different MPI implementation than the used mpirun results in errors:

```
(py36env) me@login-e-11:~$ mpirun -n 5 python -m mpi4py.bench helloworld
Hello, World! I am process 0 of 1 on login-e-11.
Hello, World! I am process 0 of 1 on login-e-11.
Hello, World! I am process 0 of 1 on login-e-11.
Hello, World! I am process 0 of 1 on login-e-11.
Hello, World! I am process 0 of 1 on login-e-11.
```

This should actually be (see https://mpi4py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html#testing):

```
$ mpirun -n 5 python -m mpi4py.bench helloworld
Hello, World! I am process 0 of 5 on localhost.
Hello, World! I am process 1 of 5 on localhost.
Hello, World! I am process 2 of 5 on localhost.
Hello, World! I am process 3 of 5 on localhost.
Hello, World! I am process 4 of 5 on localhost.
```

Comment: I'm not an expert but mpi4py may have an extension, which may be linked to Intel, if so you need to install mpi4py with gnu loaded instead of intel

Comment: @geckos But that's what I'm saying. _Despite_ unloading intel and loading gnu instead, mpi4py is _still_ being installed with intel...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When installing packages, pip keeps a cache of recently built packages. To avoid using the cache, forcing pip to rebuild the package and thereby pick up the correct environment, the `--no-cache-dir` option to `pip install` can be used.

See horovod's documentation [here](https://github.com/horovod/horovod/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.rst#pip-install-no-such-option---no-cache-dir) for further discussion.