# mpi4py getting only one MPI process available

Tags: python, mpi, hpc, mpi4py

I'm trying to use mpi4py but am getting the following error when trying to initialize it:

`Tried to create an MPI pool, but there was only one MPI process available. Need at least two.`

The value of `MPI.COMM_WORLD.Get_size()` is `1`, which confirms the issue.

Still, when I run the usual test after installing it I get the expected output, which is weird:

```
$ mpiexec -n 5 python -m mpi4py.bench helloworld
Hello, World! I am process 0 of 5 on sevrhuntd1.
Hello, World! I am process 1 of 5 on sevrhuntd1.
Hello, World! I am process 2 of 5 on sevrhuntd1.
Hello, World! I am process 3 of 5 on sevrhuntd1.
Hello, World! I am process 4 of 5 on sevrhuntd1.
```

I'm not a system admin and it is taking them a while to process my request to remove `openmpi` and install `mpich`, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29264640/mpiexec-and-python-mpi4py-gives-rank-0-and-size-1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20287564/mpi-rank-return-same-process-number-for-all-process). Is there any other way around this error?

More specifically, I'm trying to create a pool using the MPIPool class in [this file](https://github.com/Project-Platypus/Platypus/blob/62b5c23d2674839000388d463225224863d7b508/platypus/mpipool.py#L66) in the Platypus library and am getting the error here:

```py
from mpi4py import MPI


class MPIPool(object):
    def __init__(self, comm=None, debug=False, loadbalance=False):
        self.comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD if comm is None else comm
        self.rank = self.comm.Get_rank()
        self.size = self.comm.Get_size() - 1
        self.debug = debug
        self.function = _error_function
        self.loadbalance = loadbalance
        if self.size == 0:
            raise ValueError("Tried to create an MPI pool, but there "
                             "was only one MPI process available. "
                             "Need at least two.") # This is the error.
    # More code below, but not making it there.
```

when trying to initialize it with the following in my main:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = MPIPool()
```

Comment: What's your script looking like? And how do you call it?

Comment: I suspect that your pool ojbect is created with `MPI.COMM_SELF`.

Comment: how do you start your "MPIPool" program?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet, I'm embarrassed. I forgot to call python with mpiexec--as you probably thought. No wonder I was getting only one process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a stupid mistake. I just had to call Python with `mpiexec -n <# processes> python ...`. Problem solved.