# For OpenMPI, I keep getting a world size of 1, even though I am utilizing 2 processors

Tags: amazon-ec2, mpi, openmpi, mpich, starcluster

I am using OpenMPI, starcluster, and Amazon EC2, while running through the tutorials at http://mpitutorial.com/tutorials/ .  I set up a master and 2 nodes; node001 and node002.  However, whenever I call `MPI_Init` and retrieve info from the Comm about the World Size, I keep getting a "World Size" of 1, even though I definitely am using 2 processors.  These are using the functions in the MPICH library.

The example output shows the server name, rank, and world size:

```
Hello world from processor node001, rank 0 out of 1 processors 
Hello world from processor node001, rank 0 out of 1 processors
Hello world from processor node002, rank 0 out of 1 processors 
Hello world from processor node002, rank 0 out of 1 processors
```

There's obviously 2 processors here, both being used, but I still keep getting these values for Rank and World Size.  Is there a way I can look into debugging what is happening here?

Comment: Actually, a better dup would have been http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20287564/mpi-rank-return-same-process-number-for-all-process .

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I apologize for the duplicate.  I had made an attempt to search, but didn't come up with anything.  I had seen that the Ranks were all 0, but I did not know that was so tied in to World Size.

Comment: No apology necessary; this will stay as a link to the other so that people who pose the question your way will still get directed to the right answer.